# Combining multiple 5v outputs to one output

Tags: pcb, usb, encoder

I have this board [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00UUROWWK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UUROWWK) It has 3 5V outputs on it and I was wondering if there was a way to combine them to make 1 15v output? If so how can I do it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, these 5V outputs will almost certainly share a common GND.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are almost certainly not isolated. You can't stack them in series unless they are isolated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99.99% certain that those 5V outputs are parallel connected on the board so they can't be series connected off the to produce 15V

if you need 15V consider using a boost converter module.  prices start below $1 eg: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000375259194.html